# Culling mask don't work

Tags: unity, camera, culling, layers

I have the following setup: 
MainCamera render everything except ImageTurret layer.
TurretCamera render only ImageTurret layer on a RawImage

My problem is:
MainCamera render everything and TurretCamera render nothing
TurretCamera render only if set to default layer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems I was changing Layers but not all the children layers